# Sort items in a list by grouping rules

Tags: c#, algorithm

**Problem Statement**

Given a list of items each having a type associated with it, group them by the below mentioned rule

- The list should not contain consecutive items that violate the `Group` setting. For example. An item of "Type1" can have a group setting of 3. This means that there cannot be more than 3 consecutive items of "Type1"
- Any items that violate the group setting (mentioned above) should be moved down the collection. The position of insertion is determined by the `Skip` setting for that type. For example, an item of "Type 1" can have a group setting of 3 and a skip setting of 2. This means that when we encounter more than 3 consecutive items of "Type 1" then the next available point of insertion can only be after two items (Skip = 2) of type that is not of type "Type 1"
- Each item also has a weight associated with it. While moving down items by the above rule, ensure that weighting is respected except in cases where you have to break items because of grouping rule.

**Models**

```
public class Setting
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int GroupSize { get; set; }
        public int Skip { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Skip { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
    }
    public class TimelineViewModel
    {
        public TimelineViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new List<Entity>();
        }

        public string SnapshotId { get; set; }
        public IList<Entity> Items { get; set; }
        public IList<Entity> UnmatchedItems { get; set; }
    }
```

**Grouping Class**

```
public class GroupingHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> GroupSizes;

    private List<Setting> settings;
    private List<Entity> input = new List<Entity>();
    private List<Entity> temp = new List<Entity>();
    private List<Entity> output = new List<Entity>();

    //Setting class. Contains group size for each type
    public GroupingHelper(List<Setting> systemSettings)
    {
        settings = systemSettings;
        GroupSizes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < settings.Count; i++)
        {
            GroupSizes.Add(settings[i].Id, settings[i].GroupSize);
        }
    }

    public TimelineViewModel RearrangeTimeline(TimelineViewModel param)
    {
        try
        {
            input = new List<Entity>(param.Items);
            temp = new List<Entity>();
            output = new List<Entity>();
            string previous = "";
            while (input.Count != 0)
            {
                Entity item = input[0];
                var temp_item = temp.Where(x => (x.Skip <= 0) || (x.Type == item.Type && x.Weight >= item.Weight)).OrderByDescending(y => y.Weight).FirstOrDefault();
                if (temp_item != null)
                {
                    if (Validate(temp_item, ref previous))
                    {
                        if (temp_item.Type != previous)
                        {
                            Reset();
                        }
                        previous = temp_item.Type;
                        temp_item.Id = temp_item.Id + " - G"; //- G appeneded only to indicate this item was moved down
                        Add(temp_item);
                        temp.Remove(temp_item);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (Validate(item, ref previous))
                {
                    if (item.Type != previous)
                    {
                        previous = item.Type;
                        Reset();
                    }
                    Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    previous = item.Type;
                    Setting setting = settings.Where(c => c.Id.Equals(item.Type)).FirstOrDefault();
                    item.Skip = setting.Skip;
                    temp.Add(item);
                    input.Remove(item);
                }

            }
            return new TimelineViewModel()
            {
                Items = output,
                SnapshotId = param.SnapshotId,
                UnmatchedItems = temp
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Reset();
        }
    }

    #region Private Methods
    private void Add(Entity temp_item)
    {
        //decrement skip
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        {
            var k = temp[i].Skip--;
        }
        output.Add(temp_item);
        GroupSizes[temp_item.Type]--;
        input.Remove(temp_item);
    }

    private bool Validate(Entity entity, ref string previous)
    {
        if (entity.Type != previous)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (GroupSizes[entity.Type] <= 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        GroupSizes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < settings.Count; i++)
        {
            GroupSizes.Add(settings[i].Id, settings[i].GroupSize);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Test Case**

```
[TestMethod()]
public void RearrangeTimelineTest()
{
    List<Setting> setting = new List<Setting>() {
        new Setting() { Id="Type1", GroupSize = 3, Skip =2 },
        new Setting() { Id="Type2", GroupSize = 2, Skip =1 },
        new Setting() { Id="Type3", GroupSize = 1, Skip =1 },
        new Setting() { Id="Type4", GroupSize = 3, Skip =2 }
    };
    TimelineViewModel viewModel = new TimelineViewModel();
    viewModel.SnapshotId = "test_id";
    viewModel.Items = new List<Entity>() {
        new Entity() { Id = "1", Type = "Type1", Weight = 100 },
        new Entity() { Id = "2", Type = "Type1", Weight = 90 },
        new Entity() { Id = "3", Type = "Type2", Weight = 80 },
        new Entity() { Id = "4", Type = "Type2", Weight = 70 },
        new Entity() { Id = "5", Type = "Type2", Weight = 60 },
        new Entity() { Id = "6", Type = "Type2", Weight = 50 },
        new Entity() { Id = "7", Type = "Type3", Weight = 40 },
        new Entity() { Id = "8", Type = "Type3", Weight = 30 },
        new Entity() { Id = "9", Type = "Type4", Weight = 20 },
        new Entity() { Id = "10", Type = "Type3", Weight = 10 }
    };
    GroupingHelper g = new GroupingHelper(setting);
    TimelineViewModel output = g.RearrangeTimeline(viewModel);
    //This is how the final result would look
    List<Entity> output_items = new List<Entity>() {
        new Entity() { Id = "1", Type = "Type1", Weight = 100 },
        new Entity() { Id = "2", Type = "Type1", Weight = 90 },
        new Entity() { Id = "3", Type = "Type2", Weight = 80 },
        new Entity() { Id = "4", Type = "Type2", Weight = 70 },
        new Entity() { Id = "7", Type = "Type3", Weight = 40 },
        new Entity() { Id = "5", Type = "Type2", Weight = 60 },
        new Entity() { Id = "6", Type = "Type2", Weight = 50 },
        new Entity() { Id = "8", Type = "Type3", Weight = 30 },
        new Entity() { Id = "9", Type = "Type4", Weight = 20 },
        new Entity() { Id = "10", Type = "Type3", Weight = 10 }
    };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(output.Items.Select(x=>x.Id).ToList(), output_items.Select(x => x.Id).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice first question. Hopefully you will get some good reviews.

Comment: It looks like the expected result is in the same order as the initial input of `viewModel.Items`.  How can you tell the sort worked?

Answer (score 2):

#### Boolean overcomplication

Overcomplicating boolean expression is a very common beginner mistake, you can return boolean values directly without `if` statements:

```
private bool Validate(Entity entity, ref string previous) 
{ 
    return (entity.Type != previous) && (GroupSizes[entity.Type] > 0);
}
```

The code now has a better signal (information) / noise (sintactic / mechanical) ratio.

#### Duplication

`GroupingHelper` and `Reset` share an identical block of code, you should remove it from the former adding a call to the latter.